# How to skip row number for particular row in php?

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-8, counter, rowcount

Here is the piece of the code, in which the counter variable is used to add the question number automatically. I want to skip the question number if the type==4(last category) which is the question heading.

```
 @php
                    $counter=0;
                    @endphp
                    @foreach($questions as $question)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{++$counter}}</td>
                        <td colspan=4 style="text-align:left;">{{$question->title}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        @if($question->type==1)
                        @include('partials.response',['question_no'=>$question->id,'question_title'=>$question->title])
                        @elseif($question->type==2)
                        @include('partials.attendance')
                        @elseif($question->type==3)
                        @include('par`enter code here`tials.rank')
                        @elseif($question->type==4)
                        @include('partials.question-heading')
                        
                  @endif

                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: You have written an include for type 4. You wish to skip it?

Comment: No, include is used to call blade file, I just dont want that counter variable don't effect if there is question type==4

Comment: In that case, you can use simply ternary operator like `<td>{{$question->type==4 ? $counter : ++$counter}}</td>`